# How to render HTML of entity?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have created my custom entities using Entity Construction Kit module.

Is it possible to  render an HTML output of entity programatically? So I could display an entity for example in block?

I have found function [entity_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_view/7), but it returns only array, not whole HTML output.

For now, I am using Views to achieve this. I create a view that displays one instance, and  I am using function [view_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) to display HTML.

But is there any direct function, so I don't need to create a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got it working with `entity_view`, you probably just need to use:

```
print render($entity);
```

where `$entity` is the render array returned from `entity_view`.